Current working directory in Jupyter Notebook and Remote-ssh in VSC
I use VSC on two different remote servers, which I connect to via the extension remote-ssh + Python + Jupyter (the usual).
After connecting via ssh, I open a folder with the same relative path (wrt home): ~/workspace/project. The folder contains the same branch of a GitHub repository, which has a Python notebook nb.ipynb in the ~/workspace/project/src folder.
I have this problem:

one one server, the working directory printed by nb.ipynb is ~/workspace/project/src, which that does not correspond to the folder I opened in VSC, which is always the project root.

on the other server, the working directory (printed by the same notebook) is the project root: ~/workspace/project, the one I have actually selected.


I looked for settings that modify the working dir and that I might have changed, but I could not find anyone related to this. The only one seems to be:
Jupyter: Notebook File Root
Set the root directory for Jupyter Notebooks and the Interactive Window running locally.

Note: This does not apply to Remote Jupyter Kernels.

${fileDirname}

In any case, this setting has the same value in the two installations.
How do I change the folder VSC uses as working folder for the notebooks?
